# sikuli 1.0.2 documentation and ScreenRegion

Tags: java, sikuli

I'm writing program in Java, using Sikuli. I'm using sikuli-standalone***.jar, and ScreenRegion class inside of it. The problem is in documentation: http://doc.sikuli.org/

I can't find class ScreenRegion there, but I can find Screen, and Region, which have better methods (concluding by their names) than ScreenRegion. But unfortunately I don't have these classes in my library.
Acctually this does not result in compiler error:
            Screen screen = screenRegion1.getScreen();

But this does:
    Screen screen2 = new Screen();
Error is: "Cannot instantiate type Screen"

ScreenRegions seems OK, but because there is no documentation I don't know how to move/create new ScreenRegion that is moved 50px to the right on global screen.

What should I do?
What I'm doing wrong?
Is there Java documentation for Sikuli?

Answer (score 0):

OK it seems that I haven't seen it first time. This is what I should you (I think):
http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/index.html
http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html

But these classes does not work with classes in sikuli-standalone, and I'm now totally confused about what should I use. But that's topic for another question.

And this seems to be documentation for sikuli-standalone:
http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/w/list

Comment: Yes, the standalone is a rewrite of the sikuli-script.jar and not as thoroughly documented. I generally browse the bit bucket repo containing the source to gain understanding: https://bitbucket.org/doubleshow/sikuli-api/src/2899f8b3c4f5effac915478a00815075caf50446?at=master